# Typescript: Map union value to union of objects

Tags: typescript

Not a clue how to ask this well, so here is what I have and what I'm after:

Start:

```
type Initial = {
    foo: string | number
}
```

End:

```
type Final = {
    foo: string
} | {
    foo: number
}
```

I need a type using generics that I can put `Initial` into that will output `Final`.

**Edit:** (Mapping through multiple union values) [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgS2AghgGygXigbwFBSFQBmA9qQFxQDOwATgnAOZQA+UcArgLYBGEdADQEivFHSoAiMXUlsoklHFLAAFgIDK9SSMIr1dAAp1SYKrQbM8AXzx5QkWABMAPABUAfFlzWoAMlwoAG1DKEYoAGsIEFJiKDcAXSo3EITfAHp0mgRuMDQEYhA7B2gAEQQLBF5OYAgAVURSOHdBeIBpaKgIAA9auCdqSOjY+K9sETcu3oh+wcmAfl14oLcOkASpvoGwuGIBKDrCTKgAWRQoqBQoEqgwcRRuCFq6a9UUYCgAYybgFEY5lZrBJLQjzA6bGbbQ7HADq0DUMygTgq9CqNWgpAAbvsEVBOI04CCiGCYK4AEoQb50VyraKtOpeAIAeW4SBa7WiHi8xwAwnQIO9oFc4BAAO7XcDQUVIVRQABWnFoUCa0HxCCaXyatCQnBmH2IJm4y1p61aSicr2g-KVI1xYBMYEG4TcRMIVBF2LoRPdEE9SwoHoEdjwxxOT1UpAtAEZipKoAAxRjoePkbzlSrVWoNdXNeBIVBoVqSMikSQeWOORNwdBRtMohiZ+oElxV5PkIsyMt2Y6PNSRqAAJgr0FbaAHdYz6OzTRcUHTqMb09ziGQ6CLJbLHfEcnLIayTgg1AQ-ItvYjTm7WRu84b6JOnDQyDyTZz1HZawhsyGMTiniwe6ID8ei2QY1kWY4iCIG80SzZs3FaNZuSyEUIG2YBSFuFBqEGNB3glRxSBqMAah2dCvk4Oh+TgD40HIMAAMggNfSDACblHJliDOOAQAnBc7wfJ80BfLUXDzVdCwUDd5Gkbdd1YuN2M4pQeOwfAIKIEtzFRZgAG4GNEcQpE7fS9ARIwHS0ywmD045fHYNSskgzSOB4fg6BsxyDIkBRjPU0yDGMUxLMYayALs3ATJIchgt0yKZCkJR9E0bRIqS8ygpobTQts+QHMgqLKBcvgBA8-L4oURKzK0WRUrMwKzEyqzSusIA)

**Edit 2**
Thanks to the answer by Titian Cernicova-Dragomir I now have type that can distribute union values in an object into a union of objects, with no unions.

However:

The issue I'm now facing is, if I have multiple union values in an object:

```
type Initial = {
    foo: string | number,
    bar: "bar" | "anotherStr"
    otherProp: string
}

type FinalNew = {
    foo: string;
    bar: "bar"
    otherProp: string;
} | {
    foo: number;
    bar: "bar"
    otherProp: string;
} | {
    foo: string;
    bar: "anotherStr"
    otherProp: string;
} | {
    foo: number;
    bar: "anotherStr"
    otherProp: string;
}
```

I can only change 1 union value in to a union of objects at a time:

```
type DistributedFoo = DistributeUnion<Initial, "foo">

type FinalNew = DistributeUnion<DistributedFoo, "bar">
```

I cannot do both in the same pass:

```
type FinalNew = DistributeUnion<Initial, "foo" | "bar">
```

The appended question then is:

- Is it possible to do this without having to assign the output type of `DistributeUnion` to a new `type` for each key:value you need to distribute?

Comment: Will `Initial` have other properties ? Or just the one ?

Comment: it'll have others, also potentially unions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create such a type, that will take a key and a type and distribute over the type of that property:

```
type Initial = {
    foo: string | number,
    otherProp: string
}
type Id<T> = {} & { [P in keyof T]: T[P]}

type DistributeUnion<T, TKey extends keyof T> = 
  T[TKey] extends infer U  // Make a type parameter that contains T[TKey]
    ? U extends U // We then distribute over the union
      ? Id<Record<TKey, U> & Omit<T, TKey>> // Create a new type with just one union constituent from T[TKey], and the rest of the props in T
      : never
    : never;
type Final = DistributeUnion<Initial, 'foo'>

// type Final = {
//     foo: string;
//     otherProp: string;
// } | {
//     foo: number;
//     otherProp: string;
// }
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=21&ssc=5&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgS2AghgGygXigbwFBSFQBmA9qQFxQDOwATgnAOZQA+UcArgLYBGEdADQEipYAAsBABTqkwVWg2Z4AvnlCRYAEwA8AFQB8WXCqgAyXFADaUqIygBrCCFLEoegLpU9Nj2vXg0AAiCIoIvJzAEACqiKRw+oLuANLOUBAAHlFwWtSOzq7uRtgiPnqpIB7pWRA5eYzEAlDRhAD0rVAAsihOUChQGtBgKHQo3BBRdAPiKMBQAMbxwCiMeWUVHiKEAPzN1dm5e+1QAOrQErVQWqH04ZHQpABuTRdQnHFwW0S7MLoAShBFnRdOVnElokYLAB5bhIRIpZwGIzHADCdAgs2g-TgEAA7gNAlBcUhxFAAFacWhQeLQd4IeILeK0JCcWpzYiybjuKygypJFA5abQdFUwqvMCyMD1ODuL6EKg4550L4KiBKgDcAU0ADFGOhjCEwhEorF6Ql4EhUGgkgByMikG0GPB4Y6DKC6uD67D4Y5EEjkBS3Zia32iC50GRyQNKJghjqmdg+jp++0Knj8Ohxv3U8OR+Q0IOxl3xoA)

Comment: great answer, a lot to unpack from it. To clarify I'm understanding this `U extends U` is turning `string | number` into `string` then `number`? I'm now attempting to iterate over a union of keys to distribute

Comment: @MasterNoob exactly. Distributive conditional types are applied to each constituent member of a union and then the result unioned https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types

Comment: I've been trying to allow distributing 2 unions in an object like this `type Final = DistributeUnion<Initial, 'foo' | 'bar'>` but cant workout how to get the output of distributing `foo` in to `bar`, do you know of a way to do this?

Comment: I have made an edit to a playground link, containing the approach I've been taking, feels like I'm going about it the wrong way tho

Comment: @MasterNoob Not sure what you mean.

Comment: I have made a more in depth edit to the question, hope this helps